# Ubuntu Desktop VS Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, webserver, versions

So really the difference between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server is one minus servers and the latter minus a GUI, is that correct?

So if I install Desktop, I could just remove the GUI and install a web server if I wanted to?

Not trying to be funny, just trying to understand.

Comment: I read that link. It is old and doesn't specifically and directly address my questions.

Comment: "It is possible to move from a desktop system to a server system and vice-versa on an already-installed copy of Ubuntu" ... "That also means that any package that's intended for Ubuntu Server will run just as happily on your desktop installation." And if you want an update to an old post, offer a bounty on it. It's a standard bounty reason.

Comment: although it is old, the basics still apply